# Spec plugin for pytest?

Tags: nose, nosetests, specifications, pytest

Is there a plugin for py.test similar to noses's [spec](https://github.com/bitprophet/spec) (also a part of [pinocchio](http://darcs.idyll.org/~t/projects/pinocchio/doc/#spec-generate-test-description-from-test-class-method-names)). I want to see test runner output look like this:

```
Foobaz
  - behaves such and such
  - causes an error (ERROR)
  - fails to satisfy this specification (FAILED)
  - throws deprecated exception (DEPRECATED)
  - throws skip test exception (SKIPPED)
```

Testcase names transformed into list titles and testcase methods names are transformed into list items. Or module name and top-level functions, it will make sense too.

I guess it's not that hard to build one myself, but maybe there is one already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [pytest_spec](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest_spec/). It appears to do something similar to what you want, maybe not exactly though.